# API do PagSeguro não retorna o status da compra

Tags: php, api

Anteriormente tinha aberto uma dúvida de erro na API do pagseguro, bom, consegui resolver. Agora meu problema é outro... Eu não consigo receber as notificações do pagseguro. Já configurei a URL no painel do pagseguro só que não recebo nada após as compras. Eu testei o arquivo de notificação direto no navegador e ele me enviou um email (que é o que quero fazer), mas pelo pagseguro ele não retorna nada. O meu código é esse:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction'){



    $email = 'alisson@habeo.com.br';
    $token = 'MEU-TOKEN-PAGSEGURO';

    $url = 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' . $_POST['notificationCode'] . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $transaction= curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){


        exit;
    }

    $transaction = new SimpleXMLElement($transaction);

    $Ref    = $transaction->{'reference'};
    $Status = $transaction->{'status'};

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ABC <email@email.com>\r\n";

   mail('alisson@habeo.com.br', 'Teste', 'Testando', $headers);


}


?>
```

Comment: Você acessou o pagseguro na transação para ver se foi enviado notificação ? Se estiver com codigo de envio diferente de 200 tem algo errado, provavelmente a url, passada de notificação para o pagseguro

Answer (score 1):

Você não entendeu completamente o funcionamento do retorno do pagseguro por isso esta tendo problemas.

Ao final da compra o pagseguro envia para o link de retorno mas não envia nenhum dado como POST, basta identificar isso e fazer o tratamento adequado:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction'){

// Post recebido, confirmar o código de notificação e processar o retorno para obter o status atual da transação.


    $email = 'alisson@habeo.com.br';
    $token = 'MEU-TOKEN-PAGSEGURO';
...   
...   
...   

} else {

// POST não recebido, indica que a requisição é o retorno do Checkout PagSeguro.
// No término do checkout o usuário é redirecionado para este bloco.

    // redirecione para uma pagina de confirmação por ex.:
    header("Location: index.php?pag=fatura&retorno=pagseguro");

    // ou inclua aqui mesmo a mensagem, por ex:

    echo '<h4>Pagamento em Processamento</h4>
    <p>Seu pagamento será processado pelo PagSeguro e o recibo será emitido automaticamente.</p>
    <p>Obrigado.</p>
    <p><strong>Empresa XYz.</strong></p>';
}
?>
```

O envio do POST é feito pelos retornos automáticos, que são disparados quando um cliente efetua um pagamento de boleto (no outro dia), ou quando a compra no cartão é efetivada e confirmada pela operadora (alguns minutos depois), e esses eventos não ocorrem no exato momento que o cliente finaliza a compra no gateway...

Answer (score 1):

É bom verificar se o email e tokens estão corretos:

Como não se pode imprimir nada na tela pois o PagSeguro envia esses dados via POST em uma outra sessão, crie um arquivo txt (erro.txt) e coloque um código de alerta dentro da condição de autorização:

```
if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){
    //Insira seu código avisando que o sistema está com problemas, sugiro enviar um e-mail avisando para alguém fazer a manutenção
    $name = 'erro.txt';
    $text = "Transação não foi validada!" . "\r\n";
    $file = fopen($name, 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fclose($file);
    exit;//Mantenha essa linha
}
```

pode ainda verificar oque esta recebendo do pagseguro com:

```
$name = 'erro.txt';
$text = var_export($transaction, true) . "\r\n";
$file = fopen($name, 'a+');
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para receber o retorno automático do Pagseguro, é necessário que o servidor onde se encontra a sua aplicação esteja com ModSecurity desligado.

ModSecurity é um firewall para aplicação web que funciona como uma ferramenta de detecção e prevenção de intrusos. **Desligá-lo pode ser um risco para a aplicação**. Mas é o único modo de receber os dados do Pagseguro.

Segue um exemplo de configuração em um ambiente de hospedagem da Kinghost http://prntscr.com/4oa41h

Comment: Se tiver acesso a modificação das regras, basta editar e remover apenas a(s) regra(s) que estão filtrando o pagseguro, não é preciso desativar todo o modulo. (é possível identificar as regras nos logs) e o retorno do checkout que ele se refere é feito pelo browser do cliente sem POST, então não cai nas regras do modsecurity...

Comment: Raramente as empresas de hospedagem compartilhada (Locaweb, Kinghost, etc) permitem fazer tais modificações no firewall. Somente mesmo se estiver utilizando uma solução Cloud gerenciada pelo próprio cliente.

Comment: Bem por isso iniciei a frase com: "Se tiver acesso" caso alguém com servidor dedicado proprio caia aqui, veja que tem alternativa e não simplesmente desativar o modulo...

Comment: Meio radical desligar o ModSecurity. Seria mais sensato configurar para a aplicação desejada em vez de desligar. Lembrando que você pode fazer isso na configuração local, não apenas na global. **[Leitura recomendada](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2011/08/modsecurity-advanced-topic-of-the-week-exception-handling.html)** (en)

Answer (score 0):

olha pelo que vi deve ser o que o amigo William disse porque estou utilizando um código parecido com o seu e no meu funcionou. mais é simples só funciona se vc receber o post da uol. tem o ambiente de teste da uol também nele tem um retorno em um arquivo de log lá da pra vc ver qual o erro está dando.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o Mod_Security esta ativado e bloqueando as respostas do pagseguro. No meu site este era o problema e resolve fazendo o seguinte:

- Vai ate os logs do seu apacha, geralmente na pasta `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` e pesquisa por `pagseguro`.
- Ao encontrar, procura na mesma linha o id dessa transação, geralmente `[id=xxxxxx]` (um numero aleatório).
- Então vai nas configurações do Mod_Security (se vc tiver acesso) que geralmente fica em `/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-xxx/xxx.conf` e adicione uma linha com isso na configuração: `SecRuleRemoveById xxxxxx`

Salve, dê um restart no `httpd` e teste. Os locais podem ser diferentes pois eu uso o Centos Web Panel, mas pelo que vi o local do error_log costuma ser o mesmo, mas do mod_security que não... ai você tem q achar.